# How to check whether computer capable to run tensorflow gpu and how to install tensorflow gpu version

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, gpu, conda

First, I am not sure my computer(macbook pro) is capable of running tensor flow on GPU. I have checked system/hardware/Graphics-Display settings. You can find below related infos.

Graphics: Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

[image]

So, Is it possible to run tensor flow on GPU with this computer graphics capabilities?

Second question, I am using conda environment to install tensor flow. On tensorflow installation page I could only find pip package for cpu. How could I install tensor gpu package? [tensorflow installarion page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package)

> https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest version of tensorflow does not have gpu support for mac os, as seen [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac).

Comment: what about first part of the question? is it a suitable computer using GPU on machine learning? (Tensorflow does not support but for supporting libraries)

Comment: That's a different question entirely "Is my GPU good enough for machine learning". They cant run tensorflow GPU, you need a nivida graphics card because there is no [open cl support yet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22) . In general, your CPU will probably be just as efficient

Answer (score 0):

I havent found any way to run my application (which uses tensorflow) with gpu support in my Mac. It has an "Intel Iris Ghaphics 6100" graphic card.
In this report ([Can I run Cuda or opencl on intel iris?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40560336/can-i-run-cuda-or-opencl-on-intel-iris)) says that only NVDIA ghaphic cards have CUDA supports, then likely I wont be able to do ..

But I have installed tensorflow-gpu without problems following this ways:
https://wangpei.ink/2019/03/29/Install-TensorFlow-GPU-by-Anaconda(conda-install-tensorflow-gpu)/